# Is there a website which allows you to view any other website to get around firewalls blocking URLs?

Tags: url, web, blocking

I seem to remember there was a website where you could view other websites from. Does anyone know its address?

The idea being that maybe your own firewall blocked a URL. So you go to this site, enter a URL and it displays your requested URL in an iframe. The net effect is your are viewing the site as though you had gone their directly but actually you are viewing it in an iframe.

Comment: An iframe wouldn't allow you to get around blocks as your browser would still be requesting resources directly from the blocked website. Instead what you're probably talking about is an HTTP proxy. Kolink's answer describes how to make a very basic one.

Comment: It may not have been an iframe, but there was a website that allowed you to do this. Just hoping someone knows its URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a proxy. Just google proxy or web proxy and you'll find many such options.

For example: [Hide My Ass! Free Proxy](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it yourself, it's a one-liner in PHP:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Then if that's uploaded to http://example.com/getpage.php, you just need to go to http://example.com/getpage.php?url=http://google.com/ (You may need to urlencode the query string and add urldecode() around the $_GET['url'], depending on the server).

Comment: Of course, if you want to implement POST, or even have links work without needing to type the URL yourself every time, you'd need something a bit more complex ;)

Comment: True, that's quite simple - but I don't want to do it myself, there is already a service for this - somewhere???